# iText PDF A-2 with English and Hindi Fonts

Tags: java, itext, truetype, embedded-fonts, pdfa

I am using `PdfAWriter` to create a `PDF A-2` document as below

```
PdfAWriter writer = PdfAWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest), PdfAConformanceLevel.PDF_A_2A);
```

For adding text I am using TTF fonts like this

```
Font font8 = new Font(BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED), 8);
```

I need to create a PDF A-2 file with both English and Hindi fonts. For English I use `OpenSans-Regular.ttf` and for Hindi I can use `Kruti_Dev_010.ttf`, but if I use `Kruti_Dev_010.ttf` it does not render anything in English.

How can I create a PDF with both English and Hindi text?

Comment: Have you tried using a font that supports both Hindi and English? (Most Unicode Devanagari fonts also support ASCII characters.)

Comment: @PeterConstable could you please provide me an example available online?

Comment: Have you tried [Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=devanagari)?

Comment: @PeterConstable Thanks, I hadn't tried that earlier, if you would post this as an answer I can mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?subset=devanagari) has fonts that support Devanagari script and also Basic Latin characters.